# Codeigniter Mail not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am sending an email using the following code. But it shows up in my email as from "me@gmail.com" also when I press reply on the email it wants to send it to "me@gmail.com"
Don't know if I've done something wrong or?

```
$this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('thename'));
$this->email->reply_to($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('thename'));
$this->email->to('me@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('New Feedback');
$this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: I think the reply_to is redundant here..

Comment: Try with $this->email->from($this->input->post('email')); and $this->email->reply_to($this->input->post('email'))

Comment: if there is any exception?

Comment: Reading the docs it looks like reply_to() is optional, used for specifying a reply to address other than the one given in from()

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: Hi I did not solve the problem as of yet. Will be looking into it more tomorrow.

Comment: I got this working will explain in new post. It is quite funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a simple email test in CodeIgniter v 2.1.2 as follows:

```
    $this->email->from('malcom@awdoffice.com','Malcom');
    $this->email->reply_to('awd@awdoffice.com','AWD');

    $this->email->to('marc@awdoffice.com');

    $this->email->subject('Subject Mailer-Test');
    $this->email->message('Lorem est email.');

    $this->email->send();

    $rc_email = $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I suggest that you go through the following debugging procedure.

(1) Hard code all email addresses and names in the from and reply_to setters. Test to see if the problem still exist.

(2) If step (1) fixes the problem, then something may be wrong with your input variables so try printing out the variables (append to email body text).

(3) Print out the text returned from print_debugger

(4) I tested the email in Mozilla Thunderbird and the from, reply_to and to fields worked as expected.  What email client are you using? what email server (if testing locally)?

Please keep us posted with your progress.

Comment: Accepting your answer as correct, because it is point 4 that made me realize I was using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had uploaded the site to my "real" server and forgot to change the baseurl of the site.. I still had it as localhost. So whenever I sent an email it was using my localhost and the from email I had setup in phpmailer.

I know quite a silly mistake, but being up for 20+ hours can do that to someone.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Hello James, glad that my comments were able to lead you to debugging the problem.  These silly mistakes happen to all of us and it is very helpful to have a second set of eyes to see the obvious.  Good luck with your work!